# Cannot seek to byte

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I use PHP SDK on EC2.When I want to download a big file from s3. I use this code:

```
$clif = S3Client::factory(array(
'key'      => DIR_UEK,
'secret'   => DIR_UESK)); 

$clif->registerStreamWrapper();

$context = stream_context_create(array(
's3' => array(
    'seekable' => true
)));
$stream = fopen("s3://{$bucketname}/{$key}", 'r',false,$context);
fseek($stream,$byte_from);
```

where $byte_from is defined by HTTPRANGE.(this is part of my code)
When I check error.log I can see this error:

Cannot seek to byte 320971748 when the buffered stream only contains 0 bytes

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When a seekable stream is opened, you can only seek on read bytes. [1](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/3.87.17/docs/service/s3-stream-wrapper.rst#opening-seekable-streams)

You need to read `$bytes_from` before you can seek it.

```
// Read $bytes_from bytes from stream
fread($stream,$byte_from);

fseek($stream,$byte_from);

// Read $next_chunk bytes after $bytes_from
fread($stream, $next_chunk);
```

Remember to have enough storage on disk because for large files greater than 2MB, streamed data is written to disk.